# How to implement a select-like function

Tags: python

I got a dataset in python and the structure of it is like

```
Tree Species  number of trunks
------------------------------
Acer rubrum          1
Quercus bicolor      1
Quercus bicolor      1
aabbccdd             0
```

and I have a question of can I implement a function similar to

```
Select sum(number of trunks)
from trees.data['Number of Trunks']
where x = trees.data["Tree Species"]
group by trees.data["Tree Species"]
```

in python?  x is an array contains five elements:

```
x = array(['Acer rubrum', 'Acer saccharum', 'Acer saccharinum',
'Quercus rubra', 'Quercus bicolor'], dtype='<U16')
```

what I want to do is mapping each elements in x to trees.data["Tree Species"] and calculate the sum of number of trunks, it should return an array of

```
array = (sum_num(Acer rubrum), sum_num(Acer saccharum), sum_num(Acer saccharinum), 
sum_num(Acer Quercus rubra), sum_num(Quercus bicolor))
```

Comment: Isn't this what pandas is for?

Comment: You've told us where you want to go, but not where you're starting your trip. Asking "how do i implement a select-like function" is like saying how do I get to London. The answer is, it depends on where you start. For example if your data is in a pandas [data frame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) you'll want a totally different answer than if your data is in a database which python is accessing using [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html).

Answer (score 2):

Did you want to look at Python Pandas. That will allow you to do something like

```
df.groupby('Tree Species')['Number of Trunks'].sum()
```

Please note here `df` is whatever the variable name you read in your data frame. I would recommend you to look at pandas and `lambda` function too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame()
tree_species = ["Acer rubrum", "Quercus bicolor", "Quercus bicolor", "aabbccdd"]
no_of_trunks = [1,1,1,0]
df["Tree Species"] = tree_species
df["Number of Trunks"] = no_of_trunks
df.groupby('Tree Species').sum() #This will create a pandas dataframe
df.groupby('Tree Species')['Number of Trunks'].sum() #This will create a pandas series.
```

You can do the same thing by just using dictionaries too:

```
tree_species = ["Acer rubrum", "Quercus bicolor", "Quercus bicolor", "aabbccdd"]
no_of_trunks = [1,1,1,0]    
d = {}
for key, trunk in zip(tree_species, no_of_trunks):
    if not key in d.keys():
        d[key] = 0
    d[key] += trunk         
print(d)
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @StephenRauch